# Задача по sql, как найти поставщиков и детали?

Tags: sql

Подскажите, как решить данную задачу? что-то не получается
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ef32/4
Есть 4 таблицы:
поставщиков, деталей, проектов и поставки(поставщик,деталь,проект,количество)

Найти все пары "номер поставщика—номер детали", причем только такие, в которых данный поставщик не поставляет данную деталь.

**P.S.**
таблицы:
поставщиков(s), деталей(p), проектов(j) и поставки(spj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи необходимо воспользоваться оператором `EXISTS`, который принимает значение `TRUE`, если подзапрос содержит любое количество строк, иначе его значение равно `FALSE`. Для `NOT EXISTS` все наоборот.

```
select
  *
from s, p
where not exists
  (select
     null
   from spj
   where spj.s = s.s
   and   spj.p = p.p)
```

Внутри подзапроса `EXISTS` можно не выбирать никаких столбцов. В *Oracle*, например, это позволяет сократить время выполнения запроса.

Comment: а при чём здесь таблица проектов? ваше решение не соответствует задаче

Comment: Напишите буквы для таблиц в вопросе иначе не понятно. По данным, которые в таблицах получается, что `p` - это деталь, а `j` - это поставщик. Тут таблицы проектов `s` нет.

Comment: добавил описание: таблицы поставщиков(s), деталей(p), проектов(j) и поставки(spj)

Comment: Поменял буквы. Запрос аналогичный.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: отлично, благодарю за решение, не видел ещё таких подзапросов с null